# VBA transferring data between workbooks error due to space in sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on this VBA code:
(Step 1) select a particular workbook (e.g. Workbook2)
(Step 2) it auto copies  a range of data from a sheet (Raw Data) in Workbook2
(Step 3) it auto pastes the data into Workbook1 under the sheet "Accounting Data".

The sheet I want copied has the same name in all the selected workbooks (whether its Workbook2,3,4 etc.) its always named "Raw Data".

Everything works beautifully except that the code will not run if the sheet is named "Raw Data".  It only works without a space "RawData". I can't seem to figure it out.  Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Sub Get_Data_From_File()
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        OpenBook.Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:E20").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Accounting Reports").Range("A10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OpenBook.Close False
        
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly happens when it doesn't work?  Is it possible that the space in the worksheet tab name is not a space but some other character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

It's possible your "Raw Data" sheet doesn't have a space in its name but something else which maybe looks like a space.

Try running this with the workbook open and that sheet active:

```
Dim i As Long, s As String

s = Activesheet.Name
For i = 1 to Len(s)
    Debug.Print Mid(s,i,1), Asc(Mid(s,i,1))
Next i
```

Does the "space" character show up as 32, or some other code?  At a guess it might be 160 (non-breaking space).

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but I re-entered the original code and was able to get everything working.   Thanks anyways.